# Using cython produces error (methodobject.c) but pure python implementation works

Tags: python, cython

I have the following class for using and manipulating images with pygame:

```
class Image:
    def __init__(self,file_path=None, width=0, height=0):
        try:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(file_path)
        except:
            raise IOError
        self.width = self.image.get_size()[0]
        self.height = self.image.get_size()[1]

    def copy(self):
        return Image(0, 0, self.file_path)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        x, y = key
        internal_pxarray = pygame.PixelArray(self.image)
        rgb_int = internal_pxarray[x][y]
        rgb = self.image.unmap_rgb(rgb_int)
        if len(rgb) == 4:
            return rgb[:-1]
        elif len(rgb) == 3:
            return rgb
        else:
            return None

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        internal_pxarray = pygame.PixelArray(self.image)
        x, y = key
        internal_pxarray[x][y] = pygame.Color(value[0], value[1], value[2])
        self.image = internal_pxarray.make_surface()
```

which I use like this:

```
image = Image('test.bmp')
window.displayImage(image)
for x in range(0, image.width):
    for y in range(0, image.height):
        ...
        image[x, y] = 250, 218, 221
```

I tried to make this faster by using cython on the module containing the Image class but when I run the code now this line `internal_pxarray[x][y] = pygame.Color(value[0], value[1], value[2])` seems to cause the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../pink.py", line 13, in <module>
    image[x, y] = 250, 218, 221
  File "imgproc.py", line 51, in imgproc.Image.__setitem__ (imgproc.c:2256)
    self.image = internal_pxarray.make_surface()
SystemError: /Users/sysadmin/build/v2.7.3/Objects/methodobject.c:120: bad argument to internal function
```

and I can't figure out why, I've tried stepping through with pudb but everything seems fine.

The corresponding line in the compiled *.c file is `__pyx_t_6 = PyObject_Call(__pyx_t_5, ((PyObject *)__pyx_empty_tuple), NULL); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_6)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 50; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}`

Looking at [methodobject.c](https://github.com/yaogangqiang/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Objects/methodobject.c) it seems that this error is raised as the default (via `PyErr_BadInternalCall();` in `PyObject_Call` when the method arguments aren't valid. But my C knowledge is too limited to figure our exactly whats going on here.

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: What did you change in your code to use cython ? Did you do any declarations or just compiled the pure python code ?

Comment: I just compiled the pure python code using the setup.py from the cython getting started docs.